# how to send data using ajax post method?(node.js mogodb)

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb

I want to insert my data like this  :

```
{name:john,address:[{houseName:gbu,place:vypin,pin:3322}]}
```

but when I post this using ajax that `req.body` getting like this

```
{name:john,address[0][houseName]:gbu,address[0][place]:vypin,address[0][pin]:3322}
```

suggest me is there any easy method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rewrite the json in a new variable like that:

```
var json = {
   name: req.body.name,
   address: []
};

req.body.address.forEach(function (address) {
   json.address.push({
      houseName: address.houseName,
      place: address.place,
      pin: address.pin
   });
});
```